# EF Core batch insertion with error tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to insert some potentially poor quality data in to the system and I need a "per row" report of what happened so i've ben trying to do this ...

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Result<Invoice>>> AddAllAsync(IEnumerable<Invoice> invoices, Guid bucketId)
{
    var results = new List<Result<Invoice>>();
    log.Debug(invoices.ToJson());
    foreach (var invoice in invoices)
    {
        try
        {
            results.Add(new Result<Invoice> { Success = true, Item = await AddAsync(invoice, bucketId), Message = "Imported Successfullly" });
            await SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            results.Add(new Result<Invoice> { Message = ex.Message, Item = invoice });
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

My problem is that after a single add call fails that attempted add is left in the change tracker so calling add again with a different item raises the exception again for the first item.

Is there a way to (without rebuilding the context) do "batch inserts" and getting details on a per row / entity level of all the issues not just the first?

Comment: Why do you not validate your data before trying to add them to your database?

Comment: Because doing so would require me to ask the question for each foreign key is s there a row on the other end. The data is already structurally validated.